# Include posts from feature category in pre_get_posts

Tags: categories, query, pre-get-posts, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have two custom taxonomy 'cities-taxonomy' and 'userfeed-taxonomy' and I am excluding all the post which has these taxonomies assigned in my blog page using pre_get_post();

Here is my query

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_filter_main_query' );

function my_filter_main_query( $query ) {

if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

    $terms1 = get_terms( array( 'userfeed-taxonomy' ), array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
    $terms2 = get_terms( array( 'cities-taxonomy' ), array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );


    $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'userfeed-taxonomy',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $terms1,
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'cities-taxonomy',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $terms2,
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        ),
    ));
}}
```

Now what I want is that if

> featured

category is assigned in addition to above taxonomies that post must not be excluded from query.

Any help appreciated, may be some other method I can alter the blog page query to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't run this code so there may be a syntax error, but the gist is to return userfeed-taxonomy with the terms specified that have featured category OR cities-taxonomy with the terms specified and featured category OR anything else that's not those taxonomies.  It's kind of clunky, maybe there is a better way:

```
    $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'userfeed-taxonomy',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $terms1
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array( 'featured' )
                ),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'cities-taxonomy',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $terms2
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array( 'featured' )
                ),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'userfeed-taxonomy',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $terms1,
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'cities-taxonomy',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $terms2,
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        )
    ) );
```

Comment: Thanks a nice try,I have edited your answer to make it work for me.